# R CMD Check warning

Tags: r

When running R CMD Check on a large package which I did not write, I get the below warning. I've been thru the whole package and added `dplyr::` or `dbplyr::` to namespace calls.

```
W  checking dependencies in R code (3.4s)
   '::' or ':::' imports not declared from:
     'dbplyr' 'dplyr'
```

Going thru every file line by line is not something I want to do due to the size of the codebase! How can I find which lines of code include a non-namespaced call?

Comment: That error seems to imply that you did not list those decencies in your DESCRIPTION file. Do you have those packages listed under depends or imports? What exactly does your DESCRIPTION file look like?

Comment: You are exactly right. I was sure I had added those, but had not. Could you put as answer?